# Подскажите как сократить код на jQuery (События)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse-event

Доброго времени суток.
Написал такой код, но уверен что он написан далеко не идеально.
Подскажите, пожалуйста как его сократить?

```
    $("#text-chords a").on("mouseover", function(){
        var hoverChord = $(this).html(),
            activeChord = $(".tab_chords [data-chord-tab='"+ hoverChord +"']");
        activeChord.css("border-color", "red"); //Навел мышь - такой цвет
    });

    $("#text-chords a").on("mouseout", function(){
        var hoverChord = $(this).html(),
            activeChord = $(".tab_chords [data-chord-tab='"+ hoverChord +"']");
        activeChord.css("border-color", "#ddd"); //Убрал мышь - такой цвет
    });
```

Comment: убрать код уогда убираешь мишь.. просто задай дефолтный `css`вообще подсветку когда курсор на элементе можно на чистом css сделать.. и работать быстрей будет

Answer (score 2):

Я бы делал так (Не использовать цвета в JS, где их сложнее менять. `hover` c `toggleClass` объединяет 2 функции в одну):

```js
$("#text-chords a").hover(function() {
  var hoverChord = $(this).html(),
    activeChord = $(".tab_chords [data-chord-tab='" + hoverChord + "']");
  activeChord.toggleClass("active")
});
```

```css
.tab_chords > div {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 5px;
}
.tab_chords > div.active {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text-chords">
  <a href="#">Chord1</a>
  <a href="#">Chord2</a>
</div>

<div class="tab_chords">
  <div data-chord-tab='Chord1'>Chord1</div>
  <div data-chord-tab='Chord2'>Chord2</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо) Это хорошее решение!)